# Compare date to today on gridview with some empty cells

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, date, gridview

I want to change the color of an expiration field. I want to compare the values of that column to today's date and mark them red if they are expired. Not every row  has a value. All this data is tied to a SQL datasource displayed in a gridview. When I tried to do the code through the on DataRowBound, it was telling me "String Was Not Recognized As A Valid DateTime" Any help here?  I would like it to affect the Expiration field and the Action

Thanks!

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.Equals("Vendor"))
            GridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;

        colorRed();
    }
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[10].Text);
            if (DateTime.Now < myDate)//10 is for the expired field
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the code bound in html so what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Check if `e.Row.Cells[10].Text` is null or empty **before** converting it to DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow it was a simple fix. I didn't check for the right values.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (!(e.Row.Cells[10].Text.Equals("&nbsp;")))//Needed to check for this
            {
                DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[10].Text);
                if (DateTime.Now < myDate)
                {
                    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Cells[10] contains the datetime?

Remember that Cells start index in 0

Run debug and get the value of Cells[10].Text and check if is correct

Comment: That is the correct index. I have a Gridview of 19 fields. The error gets thrown when ;nbsp; is in the text field